# How to add a search bar from a wordpress REST API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, search

I'm currently working on making a website using a Wordpress REST API for a school project. The API contains recipes in the form of wordpress posts. There is a search bar on the wordpress site, and I would like the same functionality on my website.
Is there a way I can pull the search function from the WP API or do I have to make a search function on my own. If so, where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box WordPress comes with the endpoint `GET /wp/v2/search`

- https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search

With the following options as parameters:

- `context`: Scope under which the request is made; determines fields present in response. Default `view` .One of: `view`, `embed`
- `page`: Current page of the collection. Default `1`
- `per_page`: Maximum number of items to be returned in result set. Default `10`
- `search`  Limit results to those matching a string.
- `type`: Limit results to items of an object type. Default `post`. One of: `post`, `term`, `post-format`

One of: post, term, post-format

- `subtype` Limit results to items of one or more object subtypes.
  Default: any

You can use this endpoint to consume and search data, you can always extend this endpoint or adapt to your needs with the available filters.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/